# What is causing MySQL syntax error 1064 in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col_tinyint, col_varchar)
SELECT 0, distinct(col_other_varchar) COLLATE utf8_bin FROM table_b
```

I want to select distinctively and case sensively from table_b but this query creates errors. How can I solve this?

I get the error:

> **Error is SQL Syntax #1064**

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the errors are?

Comment: Tempted to down-vote for the subject (title)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` keyword must come immediately after `SELECT`.

You should also be aware that it applies to the entire row and not to a single column, regardless of any parentheses you might choose to add.

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col_tinyint, col_varchar)
SELECT DISTINCT 0, col_other_varchar COLLATE utf8_bin
FROM table_b
```

Comment: You rock and thanks a lot. Will try it right now. I was thinking of going for Group by collate .. Let's roll.

Comment: Mark Byers, you is good, you is smart and you is beautiful. It worked like a charm. I thank thee sincerely. God bless you.